# multiple checks in a if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

In java is there a faster way of doing this?

```
if (keyCode != 66 && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 21 && keyCode != 22) {

}
```

keyCode is an int.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Faster? Is it too slow for you? Don't play optimizer. Write readable code and leave microoptimizations to the optimizer. ***Premature optimization is the root of all evil***

**Edit after josh's comment:**

If you have really many of them, put them in a container (such as a set or an array) and `find` `keyCode` in it. If you found it, then your condition is false. Otherwise it's true.

As per Dave's comment:

```
if(!MyCodesSet.Contains(keyCode)){
}
```

Comment: And by readable code he means give those constant values names, i.e. what is so important about 66, 8, 21 and 22?

Comment: What if I need to add 15 more. can I use a array somehow?

Comment: Please add: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: Premature ..." ;)

Comment: You could put all your important values in a Set (using Integer rather than int) and use if setVariable.contains(keyCode)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `switch` statement will translate to direct jumps. It is however possible that the JIT does that to your code anyway, so you have to try it out if `switch` is actually faster.